# Changing or adding class names in semantic ui on window resize using media queries

Tags: css, media-queries, semantic-ui, text-alignment, window-resize

Is there any way to change the class of a grid container in Semantic UI using media queries or does the solution lie in writing your own Javascript that adds or removes classes to your HTML?

I realize that I didn't quite phrase the quite question properly so I'm going to update it to reflect that. It was exactly about media queries vs JavaScript with regards to Semantic UI.

My problem is this: Let's say I have a stackable grid container with two columns that have classes .four.wide.column and .twelve.wide.column. By default when the window size of the browser is 1000px the text inside the columns is left aligned. However I would like to centre align the text inside the columns when the window is resized to a smaller mobile size of 767 px.

At first I thought of realigning the text inside the columns on media queries however it occurred to me that that would defeat the purpose of Semantic UI because with this solution the class names wouldn't look or behave as described. The normally left aligned column is now centre aligned but the class isn't called centre aligned. What happens if the class was centre aligned and is now left aligned but the name is the same?

Then I wondered if it was possible to add and remove classes using media queries but that doesn't seem to be possible. The one solution that I found that keeps the Semantic UI is to use JavaScript to add and remove classes however I wanted to avoid using JavaScript as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exactly you want to trigger the text-align change. If you want the alignment to change at a specific viewport width, I would recommend using css `@media` queries instead of a resize listener. For a window resize you'll also want to debounce or throttle your resize event for performance. Depending on how you do that you might experience a momentary flash of unexpected alignment. You don't have to do that with a media query and the change will be immediate.

```
.ui.grid .column {
  text-align: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .ui.grid .column {
    text-align: right;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I updated my question to clarify what I meant. I wasn't asking the question that I actually wanted to ask.